# hook_node_presave get original of translated node

Tags: hooks

I'm using a hook_node_presave and I want to detect which field is updated when the translated node is updated. Here is my code :

```
function hook_import_node_presave(\Drupal\node\NodeInterface $node) {
  if (!$node->isNew()){
    $entityFieldManager = \Drupal::service('entity_field.manager');
    $fields = $entityFieldManager->getFieldDefinitions('node', 'article');
    foreach($fields as $field_name => $field_definition) {
      foreach ($node->getTranslationLanguages() as $langcode => $langcode_value) {
        $node = $node->getTranslation($langcode);
        if ($node->get($field_name)->getValue() != $node->original->get($field_name)->getValue()) {
          // do something
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However,

```
$node = $node->getTranslation($langcode);
$node->original->get($field_name)->getValue()
```

even after "getTranslation()", "original" is still pointing to the default language.
I want to get the "original" language of the translated node.

Comment: What is the result of $node->original->getTranslation($langcode)->get($field_name)->getValue()?

Comment: Yes! Seems like it is now getting the "original" value of the translated node. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$node = $node->getTranslation($langcode);
```

This is changing the translation of the node object passed by reference. Better use a different variable:

```
$node_translated = $node->getTranslation($langcode);
```

---

```
$node->original->get($field_name)->getValue()
```

`original` is a separate node object and has to be translated separately:

```
$node->original->getTranslation($langcode)->get($field_name)->getValue()
```